# Why does the Lua REPL require you to prepend an equal sign in order to get a value?

Tags: lua, read-eval-print-loop

I need help turning off this feature if possible from the interactive mode or I'm going to go mad. The REPL insists on an equal sign before every expression if you want the value. I find this very irritating and unintuitive. To make matters worse, if you mistakenly forget the equal sign, it takes you to this secondary prompt which can only be exited by 
typing an expression that'll cause an error.

```
*** str="This is some string"
*** str
>>
>>
>> =
>>
>> =str
stdin:6: unexpected symbol near '='
*** =str
This is some string
*** #str
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '#'
*** =#str
19
***
*** 545+8
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '545'
*** =545+8
553
***
```

I need a lesson in using the REPL:
**Is there a way to get rid of the equal sign so that it behaves like other REPLs?**
**How do you exit from the secondary prompt without doing what I did?**

Comment: You mean you want `return` prepended to everything you enter?

Comment: Not sure how `return` comes in here but what I want is not to have to press `=` every time I want to see a value. It kinda beats the purpose of a repl.

Comment: The beginning `=` is shorthand for `return` in standalone Lua.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Is it necessary?

Comment: well you either have to return it or print it. pick one

Comment: i just don't get the point. Shouldn't everything that is returned be printed like every other repl out there?

Comment: Adding a lone `;` probably suffices to exit the secondary prompt.

Comment: `545+8` is *not* a Lua statement and so cannot return anything. The Lua REPL already prints any values that a statement returns but it's not able to serve as a calculator as explained.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everything you enter in [standalone Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#7) is treated as a statement, as opposed to an expression. The statements are evaluated, and their results, if any, are printed to the terminal. This is why you need to prepend `=` (*really shorthand for* `return`) to the expressions you gave as example to get them to display properly without error.

The "secondary prompt" you are seeing is what happens when you enter an incomplete statement.

> In interactive mode, if you write an incomplete statement, the interpreter waits for its completion by issuing a different prompt.

You exit from it by completing the statement.

---

However, it's not too difficult to make your own REPL that does what you want. Of course, you lose the ability to progressively build statements from incomplete chunks this way, but maybe you don't need that.

```
local function print_results(...)
    -- This function takes care of nils at the end of results and such.
    if select('#', ...) > 1 then
        print(select(2, ...))
    end
end

repeat -- REPL
    io.write'> '
    io.stdout:flush()
    local s = io.read()
    if s == 'exit' then break end

    local f, err = load(s, 'stdin')
    if err then -- Maybe it's an expression.
        -- This is a bad hack, but it might work well enough.
        f = load('return (' .. s .. ')', 'stdin')
    end

    if f then
        print_results(pcall(f))
    else
        print(err)
    end
until false
```

Comment: I'm getting `bad argument #1 to 'load' (function expected, got string)` . It works when you use `loadstring`, `loadstring("print(" .. s .. ")")()` but unfortunately, it's only usefull as a calculator.

Comment: @Segfault In Lua 5.2, use `load`; In Lua 5.1, use `loadstring`. You are probably using Lua 5.1

Comment: It works now. It's pretty good. I think I can work with this.

Comment: I would reverse the statement/expression attempts, so that `f()` will print the result (assuming that the function returns a value).

Answer (score 11):

Since Lua 5.3, you don't need the `=`, because Lua first tries to interpret it as an expression now.

From [the reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7):

> In interactive mode, Lua repeatedly prompts and waits for a line. After reading a line, Lua first try to interpret the line as an expression. If it succeeds, it prints its value. Otherwise, it interprets the line as a statement. If you write an incomplete statement, the interpreter waits for its completion by issuing a different prompt.

A little test:

```
Lua 5.3.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2014 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> str = 'hello' .. ' Lua'
> str
hello Lua
> 1 + 2
3
>
```